# Passed function is not well-serializable

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to scrape the web from a file template that contains the data of an order.

For this, I am using a puppeteer evaluation function, which works correctly while the file is in .js

However, when the "pkg" package is used to compile the .exe file or evaluate to execute and initiate a return or error: "**The passed function is not quite serializable!**"

Below is the code:

```
const dados = {name: 'foo', year: 1}
  await page.evaluate(dados => {
    let dom = document.querySelector('body');
    const tags = Object.keys(dados);

    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      const tag = tags[i];
      dom.innerHTML = dom.innerHTML.split(`{{${tag}}}`).join(dados[tag]);
    }
  }, dados);
```

Comment: could you try removing the string interpolation? (`{{${tag}}}`) as a test

Comment: @hardkoded Did not work :(

Comment: Could you add more info related to the error? the stack trace?

Answer (score 13):

I try to add `--public` argument with `pkg`.

Like: `pkg start.js -t node14-win-x64 --public`

Then I can freely use `ElementHandle.evaluate( (elem)=> elem.textContent );`

With the manual of pkg, the `--public` means that : speed up and disclose the sources of top-level project.

### BTW

**To fixup cannot find chrome binary file**

```js
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: "node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-782078/chrome-win/chrome.exe"
});
```

(The path above can set anywhere as you like.)

**To fixup start.exe cannot run**

Sometime the output binary exe cannot executable. It
always popup a new cmd prompt window when we enter `start.exe`. (or just double click.)

- Just delete the output exe then rerun pkg
- Check the code whether is runnable with `node start.js` or not

Comment: Thank you. thank you a lot. I was just about to miss deadline tomorrow :)

Comment: This saved my day! Thank you. I was getting very weird errors from opencv when running from the binary, now solved using `--public`.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution for me is to wrap it with eval() :

```js
async getText(selector: string) {
    await this.page.waitForSelector(selector);
    let text = await eval(`this.page.$eval('${selector}', el => el.textContent)`)

    return text;
}
```

or this:

```js
await eval(`this.page.evaluate(
      (selector) => { (document.querySelector(selector).value = ''); },
       selector);`);
```

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. Eval() allows any passed args to evaluate too.

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact issue relating to `puppeteer` and `pkg`. For some reason pkg doesn't correctly interpret the contents of the callback. The solution that worked for me was to pass a string to `evaluate` rather than a function:

**Change:**

```js
const dados = {name: 'foo', year: 1}
  await page.evaluate(dados => {
    let dom = document.querySelector('body');
    const tags = Object.keys(dados);

    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      const tag = tags[i];
      dom.innerHTML = dom.innerHTML.split(`{{${tag}}}`).join(dados[tag]);
    }
  }, dados);
```

**to**

```js
await page.evaluate(`
    (() => {
        const dados = {name: 'foo', year: 1};
        let dom = document.querySelector('body');
        const tags = Object.keys(dados);

        for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
          const tag = tags[i];
          dom.innerHTML = dom.innerHTML.split(`{{${tag}}}`).join(dados[tag]);
        }

        // return dom to do something with the data in node
        return dom.innerHTML
     })()`);
```

[This answer on github](https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/204#issuecomment-378929002) suggests an alternative solution - using the `pkg` api to inject the callback at compile time, however it didn't work for me.